# Are iOS apps terminated cleanly when upgraded via the AppStore?

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, app-store, testflight

We have found a data loss bug in the current version of our application because we are not saving data to disk during backgrounding, but only when `applicationWillTerminate:` is called.

So the question is, once we issue an update, will the AppStore cleanly terminate our application during the upgrade process?

Installing over the running copy with Xcode kills the process, and TestFlight also seems to not cleanly do this either.

Is there any documentation on this behavior?

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` is only called in a limited set of circumstances. You must never rely on it being called for any reason.

Comment: yes, but the previous developers didn't know that :)

Comment: But the current ones do so they can spend 5 minutes to fix it. :)

Comment: its easy to fix and we already have, but we still have a version in production affected by this issue. I want to know if we need to warn our users before they upgrade

Comment: Warning won't help because no one will see the warning or pay any attention to it. Many users have their iOS devices setup to automatically update apps.